# KVM RHEL 7.5 ,offline external snapshot taken but not able to merge now the disk with existing disk

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, rhel7

**KVM and qemu RPM info :-**

```
[root@shirish_rhel ~]#  rpm -qa | grep -i qemu
qemu-kvm-common-1.5.3-167.el7.x86_64
qemu-img-1.5.3-167.el7.x86_64
ipxe-roms-qemu-20180825-2.git133f4c.el7.noarch
libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu-4.5.0-23.el7.x86_64
qemu-kvm-1.5.3-167.el7.x86_64
qemu-kvm-tools-1.5.3-167.el7.x86_64
```

**SNapshot List**

```
[root@shirish_rhel ~]# virsh snapshot-list --domain centos7.0
 Name                 Creation Time             State
------------------------------------------------------------
 testVM2-firstSNAP35  2019-08-08 13:22:11 -0400 shutoff
 testVM2-firstSNAP36  2019-08-08 13:24:48 -0400 shutoff
 testVM2-firstSNAP37  2019-08-08 13:27:13 -0400 shutoff
```

```
[root@shirish_rhel ~]# virsh snapshot-info --domain centos7.0 --snapshotname testVM2-firstSNAP37
Name:           testVM2-firstSNAP37
Domain:         centos7.0
Current:        yes
State:          shutoff
Location:       external
Parent:         -
Children:       0
Descendants:    0
Metadata:       yes
```

**if VM is shutdown :-**

```
[root@shirish_rhel ~]#  virsh blockcommit centos7.0 vda --active --verbose --pivot
error: Requested operation is not valid: domain is not running
```

**if VM is Running :-**

```
[root@shirish_rhel ~]#  virsh blockcommit centos7.0 vda --active --verbose --pivot

error: unsupported configuration: online commit not supported with this QEMU binary
```

Answer (score 2):

The `qemu` binary shipped by default in RHEL does not support snapshot live merging. To merge your snapshot, you have two possibilities:

- shutdown the virtual machine and use `qemu-img`(see [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Virtualization_Administration_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Tips_and_tricks-Using_qemu_img.html) for an example)
- install the `qemu-kvm-ev` package from [CentOS Virtualization SIG](https://wiki.centos.org/SpecialInterestGroup/Virtualization), which has the required functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your help.